# overloaded assignment operator bus error

Tags: c++

For some reason my assignment operator produces bus error when I try and use it:

```
hand1 = hand2;


//overload assignment operator
Hand Hand::operator=(Hand other_hand)
{

    if(&other_hand != this){
        name = other_hand.name;
        cards = other_hand.cards;

    }

    return *this;   
}
```

The error occurs right after the return statement

Comment: You're taking and returning copies, you probably don't want to do that.

Comment: Copy-swap! Copy-swap!

Comment: Also, can you show us a definition of Hand? It is not clear if either name or cards have memory that needs to be managed i.e. are you doubling deleting something in the destructor?

Answer (score 1):

First of all assignment should have a signature that looks like this:

```
Hand & Hand::operator=(const Hand &other_hand)
```

You probably do not want to passing and returning a copy as was pointed out but also you want to allow operating chaining i.e.:

```
hand1 = hand2 = hand3 ....
```

This is a [basic reference](http://courses.cms.caltech.edu/cs11/material/cpp/donnie/cpp-ops.html). Also copy and swap was mentioned, this [previous thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom) does a perfect job of explaining it.